# htaccess rewrite folder with different paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an web application setup on a local and staging server. The local application has a different basepath to the staging. e.g.

Local
http://phils-imac.local/git/clients/myproject/html/

Staging
http://myserver.com/myproject/html/

I would like use htaccess to make the urls accessible without the 'html' part. e.g.
http://phils-imac.local/git/clients/myproject/
http://myserver.com/myproject/

I have been using this rewrite rule on my staging server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myserver.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myproject/html/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myproject/html/$1 [L]
```

It works ok but I feel I need to customise it for each project. Ideally I'd like the 'myproject' part to be a variable and have the rule more general so it would also work on my local path.

Comment: So what is your question? Is it "how do I use a variable in place of 'myproject'?" Where would this variable come from? The only thing preventing that rule from working on the local path as shown in your example is the line `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =myserver.com` explicitly telling it not to.

Comment: The Rewrite Rule above would rewrite to http://phils-imac.local/myproject/ instead of http://phils-imac.local/git/clients/myproject/ I'd like replace the myproject with a variable but also have the rule work with different paths not just absolutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define variables in your `.htaccess` but if you keep your project name same you can accommodate for a variable base path in your rewrite rule as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/html/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?myproject/(.*)$ $1/myproject/html/$2 [NC,L]
```

This requires your `.htaccess` in your web root directory. If your `.htaccess` resides inside your `myproject` folder try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/html/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ html/$1 [L]
```

In both the cases, you need to drop your `%{SERVER_NAME}` check as it would never match between your local and staging locations.